# Is there a way to make a responsive grid if the columns are not the same size without using media queries?

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive, minmax

I am making a webpage which is primarily made of grids, some being inside other grids. I am having trouble making it responsive. My main grid `#content` has two columns with the following size:

`grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;`

Inside, there is another grid called `#pages`. I was able to successfully make this one resize depending on screensize using `repeat`, `auto-fit`, and `minmax`:

```
#pages>div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}
```

My problem is that I want `#content` to be two columns with the size 3fr and 1fr on a desktop, but on a smaller screen size I want it to collapse into a single column. Unfortunately, as they are not the same size as with the `#pages` example, I don't know what the best way to make them responsive is. Is there a way to do this without media queries? What is the best way to achieve this?

I wrote the code pen with my progress so far where `#pages` works as intended but `#content` does not:

https://codepen.io/georgeciesinski/pen/vYrXrwb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's the best solution, but I think this is a good use-case for flexbox.

Make your `#container` `wrap` and you can set the minimum widths using the `flex` shorthand, which will translate almost directly over as:

```css
flex: 3;
```

and

```css
flex: 1;
```